# Why is my c# database loop not adding data to my gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp c# method that is supposed to bind a dataset to a gridview in my aspx file.

Now, I need to add a custom column to the grid because it's value is calculated in another class based on the value of a certain database column.  So I am using reader with a while loop to cycle through the results and then add the columns individually.  But the grid is not displayed.  Here is the code I am using now:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstring;
            connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.EnrolledStudents", conn);

            SqlDataReader reader;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Students");
                ds.Tables.Add("Students");
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Grades studentGrades = new Grades();
                    studentGrades.percentage = Convert.ToInt32(reader["percentage"]);
                    string letterGrade = studentGrades.calculate();
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("studentId", typeof(int)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("firstName", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("lastName", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("courseName", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("season", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("year", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("letterGrade", typeof(string)));

                    dr["studentId"] = reader["studentId"];
                    dr["firstName"] = reader["firstName"];
                    dr["lastName"] = reader["lastName"];
                    dr["courseName"] = reader["courseName"];
                    dr["season"] = reader["season"];
                    dr["year"] = reader["year"];
                    dr["letterGrade"] = letterGrade;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                StudentGrid.DataSource = ds;
                StudentGrid.DataBind();
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                DBError.Text = "Error getting database records...";
                DBError.Text += err.Message;
            }

        }

  }
```

Here is my aspx file:

```
<h1>Student List</h1>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GetStudents" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConn %>" SelectCommand="dbo.GetStudents" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="StudentGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="studentId" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="firstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="courseName" HeaderText="Course Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="season" HeaderText="Semester" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="year" HeaderText="Year" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="letterGrade" HeaderText="Grade" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/AddScore.aspx">Add Score</asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:TextBox ID="DBError" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

In my DBError label, I get the message Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.  Any idea why?

Comment: When you put a break point on StudentGrid.DataSource = ds. Are there any records? Also if you had to use Entity Framework you could right the same code in a few lines

Comment: No errors are given when I insert a break point there.

Comment: you add the columns for each record? - anyway no need to use a dataset - bind your grid to the datatable

Comment: You are binding the grid to a dataset, instead you must bind it to a datatable

Comment: Using a command that retrieves data using a stored procedure and not setting the CommandType to CommandType.StoredProcedure should fail. Default is CommandType.Text. What is not explicable are the missing exceptions

Comment: So I realized I was not setting the visibility of DBError label to true if there was an error... so I fixed that and I am getting the error Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: remove the try catch block and run your code, and see where it is failing. Also add corrections as @fubo suggested, you must only add columns once

Comment: Now the error is occurring on the line studentGrades.percentage =  ...

Comment: so there is your problem then, reader["percentage"] is null